# Where to call getChildFragmentManager()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager, android-nested-fragment

### Problem

According to the Google's docs:

> You can now embed fragments inside fragments. This is useful for a
>   variety of situations in which you want to place dynamic and re-usable
>   UI components into a UI component that is itself dynamic and
>   re-usable. For example, if you use ViewPager to create fragments that
>   swipe left and right and consume a majority of the screen space, you
>   can now insert fragments into each fragment page.
>        To nest a fragment, simply call getChildFragmentManager() on the Fragment in which you want to add a fragment. This returns a
>   FragmentManager that you can use like you normally do from the
>   top-level activity to create fragment transactions. For example,
>   here’s some code that adds a fragment from within an existing Fragment
>   class:

```
Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment).commit();
```

So I had (for example) `TestFragment` which looks like:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private View mFragmentView;
    private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;   

    public HistoryFragment() {
        super();
    }       

    @Override   
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater pInflater, ViewGroup pViewGroup, Bundle pBundle) {          

        mFragmentView = pInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, pViewGroup, false);         

        mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

        return mFragmentView;
    }   

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }    

    /* ISSUE */
    public void doSomethingSpecial() {
        FragmentManager tFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    }
}
```

At the `MainActivity` I initialize my fragment like:

```
mTestFragment = new TestFragment();
mTestFragment.doSomethingSpecial();
```

Then I pass fragment to `ViewPager` via `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Finally, I get an exception. But if I use only:

```
mTestFragment = new TestFragment();
```

Then it works.

### Question

Where should I call `getChildFragmentManager()` method in my fragment? What I am doing wrong?

**If you have a good example of using new Android Nested Fragments please share link with me.** I would greatly appreciate for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this link ... [getChildFragment() on Programmatically added fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757875/getchildfragmentmanager-on-programmatically-dynamically-added-fragments)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: I call and use `getChildFragmentManager()` in my Fragment's `onViewCreated()` method.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    addInnerFragment(); // This method does the getChildFragmentManager() stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I Just used in the following case.

I was trying to add a Map into a ViewPager. As you may know, the "pages" in the ViewPager are Fragments, so I was unable to use this code [Sample using maps from an Activity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/BasicMapDemoActivity.java). I was trying to get the SupportMapFragment from the Activity doing things like:

```
SupportMapFragment mapView = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

But mapView was always null, so my application crashes.

I found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109206/null-pointer-exception-at-mapfragment-getmapasyncthis-while-initializing-googl/%22Answer%22) and works inmediatly.

This can be an useful example where to use getChildFragmentManager()

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Your first link is broken and the second link doesn't provide any insight on *where* to use `getChildFragmentManager()`. :-(

Comment: That was a last year answer :/ You could edit the answer and provide feedback instead of down-voting

Comment: I'm not sure what code the link contained, so couldn't really edit your answer. I felt the answer wasn't useful, hence the downvote - but at least I left a comment! :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()), this method:

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments
>   inside of this Fragment.

So you can use it if you want to add/replace a new fragment to your existing fragment, you should commit your TestFragment transaction first, then add the inner fragment to it. try something like this:

```
    TestFragment mTestFragment = new TestFragment();
//get the activity's fragment manager to add the fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, mTestFragment).commit();
    //add the inner fragment
    mTestFragment.doSomethingSpecial();
```