# Null pointer exception at mapFragment.getMapAsync(this) while initializing google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

When I use v6.5.87 of Google Play Services, I get a null pointer exception when I call `getMapAsync()`. I'm using a `SupportMapFragment` in my `Fragment`'s xml layout.

My code:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);

mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Note: There's no problem when calling `getMap()` on older Google Play Services versions, but `getMap()` is now deprecated ([docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)).

Here's the stack trace for the NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.decos.fixi.fragments.FragmentLocationMap.initializeMap(FragmentLocationMap.java:132)
            at com.decos.fixi.fragments.FragmentLocationMap.onCreateView(FragmentLocationMap.java:95)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally I got the answer!

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
```

instead of

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
```

getChildFragmentManager() did the trick.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() this method is not find.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me as well.

Comment: Genius! Was looking for ages how to do this in my fragment.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, If you are using `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment).....`

Then be sure you have set this `class` attribute in `XML`

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Not

```
class ="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppCompatActivity extend

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment mVTMapFragment =(SupportMapFragment)mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapRideview);
mVTMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and implement onMapReady callback method

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement the callback function for your `getMapAsync()`?

If not, You need to implement the [onMapReady()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)) method in your code, and then you can do adding markers or moving camera stuff in your `onMapReady()` method.

You can see [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/android/maps-in-action) about `onMapReady()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply ztan. But I've implemented OnMapReadyCallback which overrides onMapReady() method!

Answer (score 0):

### Heading

run your program by adding this

```
 SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment
```

**ADD THIS** in **ON CREATE METHOD()**

```
supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(); 

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.maplayout, new MapFragmentClass()).commit();
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sfm = getSupportFragmentManager();
sfm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map,supportMapFragment).commit();
```

**this will work check it**

Answer (score 0):

that will work only inside of a fragment. For those who have activity and not fragment `getChildFragmentManager()` will not work.

Simply use

```
  if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
```